# Use external GPU and on board Display Adapter at the same time

Tags: gpu, on-board-peripheral

I want to use multiple monitors and I don't have enough ports, my computer can support it but I can't use my on board Display ports I have tried editing the setting to use on board display ports in the bios but I don't have the option I think I don't have UEFI to be fair I do have just a bit older computer so please help.

Comment: Can we have some details? What computer do you have, what operating system? Also what monitors are you trying to connect and how many? And to clarify, your question is how to attach more monitors in the given situation?

Comment: I have a gateway computer from 2013 (Don't know what model) AMD a6 Processor 12gb of ram(Added 8) amd/asus r7 360 GPU and it has windows 8 :)

Comment: From experience, its very dependant on your system - and how its architected. If the onboard GPU is on die - there's a better chance you can use it alongside the discrete one.

Comment: Thanks but are you sure there isn't a software that could emulate the on board Display Adapter as a GPU?

Comment: hm. No. There's a fair bit of hardware specific things that could be going on, like shared PCI lanes.

Comment: External GPUs require Thunderbolt.  Your computer doesn’t support it.  Unless you actually mean, you want to use a dedicated GPU, easy to confuse the two.

Comment: I do think he means a *discrete* GPU,